# Is it possible for your body to read with a current electrical metter with dc place on head with black an red needles to say -176.4, -142.9 an so on

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible for your body to read with a current electrical metter with dc place on head with black an red needles to say -136.4 -119.9 so on (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VRhmpfWZjeo)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the multimeter is set to the 200mV range, so -176.4 means -0.1764V. Human skin has a nonzero conductivity, so by connecting both wires with his skin he forms a loop antenna, and is probably picking up some radio transmission, or just power line noise.

Comment: I tried it with my home tools voltmeter, and yes, a signal can be seen on DC at 2000V range, stronger on the head (better conductivity?) than the hands, and the interesting thing is it is stronger the smaller the distance between the probes. It is picking a dominant frequency? The signal exists whether close to the computer or not.

Comment: There must be a rectified effect too, in the complex circuit "DC voltmeter+skin conducting", since the signal is DC